# Adding a new page to project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project using C#.

I have been using only one view, Views/Home/Index.cshtml to do most of the stuff I need the app to do.

Today I was asked to add a new page, that will serve as an "Admin" type of page to allow some basic crud operations to a record.

I am having trouble understanding how to navigate to a page other than the Home/Index.cshtml, actualy I do not even navigate to that page in the browser, since that is the default routing, the url looks like: http://localhost:51225/Meetings/Agenda/  -- this is how I can see the Index.cshtml page.

So far what I have done, in the HomeController, I added this code below the Index View:

```
    // GET: Home  
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //GET: Admin 
    public ActionResult Admin()
    {
        return View();           -- I right clicked, and added a new view named "Admin"
    }
```

My folders now look:

```
Views
    Home
        Admin.cshtml
        Index.cshtml
```

I have not changed the RouteConfig class:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
                    "Default",                                              // Route name
                    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
                );
    }
}
```

I can still open my app, and see the Index.cshtml when I go to:

```
http://localhost:51225/Meetings/Agenda
```

But I do not know how to access the Admin.cshtml
So far I know it is not by simply adding Admin at the end

```
http://localhost:51225/Meetings/Agenda/Admin
```

Nor

```
http://localhost:51225/Meetings/Agenda/Home/Admin
```

Nor

```
http://localhost:51225/Meetings/Agenda/Home/Admin.cshtml
```

Is it possible to ask for help in trying to learn how and what needs to chane in my solution in order to navigate to a different page that Index in the Home folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Custom route to the RegisterRoutes method in Route confige before default route:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "AgendaRoute",
        url: "Meetings/Agenda/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Final RouteConfig:

```
   public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AgendaRoute",
                url: "Meetings/Agenda/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Result :

```
http://localhost:51225/Meetings/Agenda => Index.html
http://localhost:51225/Meetings/Agenda/index => Index.html
http://localhost:51225/Meetings/Agenda/index/1 => Index.html

http://localhost:51225/Meetings/Agenda/admin => Admin.html
http://localhost:51225/Meetings/Agenda/admin/1 => Admin.html
```

Answer (score 1):

the default routing convention of ASP.NET MVC is  Controllername/Action/parameter.
Lets say for example you have a Route like `Products/Create`, ASP.NET will search for an Action named Create in ProductsController and the view will be `Create.cshtml` inside the `Products` directory.

I suggest you follow that convention and create an AdminController and put Index action on the controller. Which you can Access by `localhost:51225/Admin/Index`. For the views, the convention is it searches for a view with the same name as the action,, that is you create a folder named Admin and put Index.cshtml inside it

Answer (score -1):

You can always access anything by /ControllerName/ViewName/ParametersIfNeeded. I suggest you to add a button on the navigation bar which will be visible only for admins, and so that only they can visit that page. In your case the admin View can be accessed with http://localhost:51225/Home/Admin.